# How does World of Warcraft being Free-to-Play* work with existing accounts?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

*WoW* is now [F2P up to level 20](https://us.battle.net/account/creation/wow/signup/;jsessionid=B104E8AC8F8D1B5DC054E98E99C93BD5.blade34_04_bnet-mgmt), so can I make and play some twinks on an existing account (and maybe just be locked out of my 85's)?  Or do you need to make a wholly new account?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Free to Play" bit is only for trial accounts. Accounts that have previously been full accounts will need to be resubscribed, and can not be played for free up to level 20.

Comment: The accounts aren't trial, you can play them forever, but they have a bunch of restrictions related trading and chat.

Comment: They are in fact trial, its called "Endless Trial" you will have trial restrictions on you and be treated as a trial account until you buy the game.

Comment: @Pyrodante Agreed, the previous Trial Accounts only lasted 1 week if I am remembering correctly.

Comment: @Ravekner I guess that's why they call them "endless trial" now.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new WoW-starter-account inside your exisiting Battle.net account, when you log in the game asks which one to use.